# capitalized short form for month in Spark SQL date

Tags: sql, date, apache-spark-sql, date-format

```
SELECT date_format(to_date('08/15/1990 12:03:00 PM', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:SS a'),"dd-MMM-yy")
```

is printing  **15-Aug-1990**. I need a capitalized short form for month in the date like **15-AUG-1990**. How to do that using Spark SQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UPPER(date_format(to_date('08/15/1990 12:03:00 PM', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:SS a'),"dd-MMM-yy"))
```

May help others.